# Calculate average price and number of unique buyers for each seller and visualize

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following data frame:

```
      seller_id| buyer_id| quantity| price | transaction_date

          1432 | 344     |   40    | 3420  | 2015-02-01
          1432 | 356     |   41    | 3420  | 2015-02-01
          1432 | 354     |   41    | 3420  | 2015-02-03
          1456 | 354     |   41    | 3420  | 2015-02-04  
          1498 | 354     |   41    | 3420  | 2015-02-04
```

For every seller I want to find the number of unique buyers and the average purchase price across all the unique seller's sales. I then want to visualize this data, as I have 200 unique sellers, to see the distribution of all sales for all the sellers in the system.

So for seller_id 1432 the average sales would be $3420

I tried `df.groupby(['seller_id', 'buyer_id'])['amount'].transform(avg)`

It is not returning the results I want.

Comment: `df.groupby(['seller_id'])['amount'].mean()`?

Comment: What else have you tried? Have you read the Pandas docs?

Answer (score 1):

Create your pandas `DataFrame`

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = \
"""seller_id|buyer_id|quantity|price|transaction_date
1432 | 344     |   40    | 3420  | 2015-02-01
1432 | 356     |   41    | 3420  | 2015-02-01
1432 | 354     |   41    | 3420  | 2015-02-03
1456 | 354     |   41    | 3420  | 2015-02-04  
1498 | 354     |   41    | 3420  | 2015-02-04  
"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep='|')
```

Then create your statistics per `'seller_id'`

```
sellers_stats = df.groupby(['seller_id']).agg({'price': 'mean', 'buyer_id': pd.Series.nunique}).reset_index()
sellers_stats.columns = ['seller_id', 'avg_price', 'unique_buyers']
sellers_stats
```

Then you can plot

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = [str(x) for x in sellers_stats['seller_id']]
y = [x for x in sellers_stats['unique_buyers']]
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.set(title='Unique buyers per seller')

plt.show()
```

[image]

and

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = [str(x) for x in sellers_stats['seller_id']]
y = [x for x in sellers_stats['avg_price']]
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.set(title='Average amount per seller')

plt.show()
```

[image]

or you can make a single plot

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

width = .35 # width of a bar
sellers_stats['avg_price'].plot(color='blue', kind='bar', width=width)
sellers_stats['unique_buyers'].plot(color='red', secondary_y=True)

ax = plt.gca()
plt.xlim([-width, len(sellers_stats['seller_id'])-width])
ax.set_xticklabels([str(x) for x in sellers_stats['seller_id']])

plt.show()
```

[image: bar line plot]

Answer (score 0):

1. df.groupby(['seller_id','buyer_id']).count() <- number of unique buyers per seller
2. df.groupby(['seller_id','buyer_id']).mean()['amount'] <- average buying amount per buyer per seller

Oh I thought this is what you want, this should do the work for you
data.groupby(['seller_id']).buyer_id.nunique()

Comment: For 1. this gives me all the buyer_ids for a given seller in a nested way and doesn't give me an actual count. So for each seller id I have all the unique buyers listed out but not a count.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimum complete example that returns the two requested data frames:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = \
"""seller_id|buyer_id|quantity|amount|transaction_date
1432 | 344     |   40    | 3420  | 2015-02-01
1432 | 356     |   41    | 3420  | 2015-02-01
1432 | 354     |   41    | 3420  | 2015-02-03
1456 | 354     |   41    | 3420  | 2015-02-04  
1498 | 354     |   41    | 3420  | 2015-02-04  
"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep='|')

nbs = df.groupby(['seller_id']).buyer_id.nunique()
print("Number of buyer per seller")
print(nbs)

avgpp = df.groupby(['seller_id']).mean()['amount']
print("Average purchase price across all the unique seller's sales")
print(avgpp)
```